# Mac Excel generate UTF-8

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Is it possible to generate a UTF-8 file using Visual Basic (VBA) in Excel 2016 for Mac?
I need to generate an XML or TXT file that is encoded.

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to do this in Excel for Mac. You will need to use a full Excel client.

Comment: I haven't done VBA on the Mac, but perhaps if you can't do it directly, you can save a text file with whatever default encoding is used and then let Apple Script change the encoding, with the AppleScript invoked from VBA using  `AppleScriptTask command`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt654021.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Not UTF-8, but **UTF-16** is what VBA uses internally, so you can dump string data directly:

```
Dim fnum As Integer
fnum = FreeFile()
Open "utf16.txt" For Binary Access Write As fnum

'write UTF-16 Byte Order Marker
'
Put #fnum, 1, &HFE
Put #fnum, 2, &HFF

printLineUtf16 fnum, "Olá Mundo!"

Close #fnum

Function printLineUtf16(fnum As Integer, str As String)

    str = str & ChrW(10)            'append newline

    Dim data() As Byte              'coerce string to bytes
    data = str

    Put #fnum, LOF(fnum) + 1, data  'append bytes to file

End Function
```

This should work in Excel Mac 2011 and 2016, and in Windows versions. Note that you won't be able to type Unicode string literals in the editor, just simple accented Latin letters like the "á" above, but strings assigned from the `Value` of a cell will be preserved in Unicode.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to work. If you look at the file in hexadecimal, you can see that Excel always adds the bit sequence "000A00" at the end. This leads to errors in other programs.      AS-IS: `printLineUtf16 fnum, "á"` = `FEFF00E1 000A00`    TO-BE: `FEFF00E1` Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Note that the one above won't work on M1 Macs because the VBA functions EOF and LOF don't work unless running the Office app under Rosetta 2. There's an error trapping solution for EOF but I haven't seen anything for LOF yet.

Answer (score 1):

After 4 years of research ;), this is the best solution I came up with:

```
Sub test()
    Dim xmlStr As String
    xmlStr = "<h1 class=""bold"">UTF8 Test -ÄÖÜêçñù-</h1>"
    writeToFile xmlStr, "utf8.html"
End Sub


Function writeToFile(str As String, filename As String)
    'escape double quotes
    str = Replace(str, """", "\\\""")

    ' use Apple Script and shell commands to create and write file
    MacScript ("do shell script ""printf '" & str & "'> " & filename & " "" ")

    ' print file path
    Debug.Print "file path: " & MacScript("do shell script ""pwd""") & "/" & filename
End Function
```

I have not found a way to break out of the Apple sandbox environment. Therefore, I write all files to the Excel sandbox container path:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data
```